# return a element.onerror function value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a value inside a function but the variable is only changed inside a function. outside the function the variable remains the same.

I have tried the following:

```
//variable file_exist still has the value true in it.
img.onerror = function () {
        file_exist = false;
};

 //returns function(){ reutnr false;};
file_exist = img.onerror = function () {
        return false;
};
```

I cant seem to get the value outisde of this function. Is there a way to get the value false?

full code:

```
 var i = 1;
 var file_exist = true;
  while(file_exist){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "ws-img/"+id+"-"+i+".jpg";
    //deleted some code since no need here for the exampled
    img.onerror = function () {
         file_exist = false;
        console.log(file_exist);//shows false
    };
    console.log(file_exist);//shows true
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `img.onerror` will only trigger when there is an error, so `file_exist` is not set unless/until the error occurs.  What you are calling "outside the function" is actually "before the function".  Can you explain what you are trying to do (please don't just explain that you want to return the value of that function - explain *why*)

Comment: how would i fix that? :(

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to do I can't answer you.

Comment: I need to loop throught a src of imgs until there isnt any left on the server. I dont know how many there could be therefore I need some kinda of loop that integrates 1 by 1. that number is then used to see if image exist, if it doesnt exist then its the end of the search, where file_exist turn false and exist while loop

Comment: Okay - you can do that very similar to what you have above, but you must wait for each image to load before trying the next.  That's probably not going to be what you want.  The alternative is to get the info from the server without having to load images.

Comment: Thanks, i have a function to get the info from the server, but I found it was taking a little bit to load the imgs to the webpage. this way is faster, but the problem is the while loop is infinity atm.

Comment: How were you getting the info from your server and what info were you getting?

Comment: using XMLHttpRequest then send via HEAD plus the img url, and returning true if statues is not 404

Comment: That's not what I meant.  You're right that that will be slower since you're making 2 requests for every image.  What I meant was having a method of querying the server for the list of images, (or number of images if that really is 100% foolproof), like an API call.  What is the server-side language, or is this 100% client-side?

Comment: I get some information before hand using php, but at this stage is 100% client-side. "or number of images if that really is 100% foolproof" I didnt think of that one, I could certainly do that in the earlier stage when using php. then at this stage just loop the number of imgs. Thanks :)

Comment: I'll add some code to do what you're asking, but really you'd be a LOT better off just adding the images to the page with PHP, on the server (search the folder, add the images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my preferred method, but it will work in your specific scenario...

```
var imageCount = 0;

function loadImage(onComplete) {
    imageCount++;

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.onerror = function () {
        // there was an error, so we're assuming there are no more images
        onComplete();
    };

    img.onload = function() {
        // the image has loaded - add it to the DOM?
        // call this function again to load the next image
        loadImage(onComplete);
    };

    img.src = "ws-img/" + id + "-" + imageCount +".jpg";

    // cached images won't trigger onload
    if (img.complete) img.onload();
}}

loadImage(function() {
    alert("images have all loaded");
});
```

It creates the image element, as you were doing, for image #1, then on success it will increment the counter and run itself again.  That will try and load image #2, and so on and so on.  When it errors it stops and executes the callback function so you know all the images are loaded.

There are issues with this though.  If an image doesn't load for *any* reason, it will stop and load no more images.  A much better solution would be to either construct the page with all the images, using server-side code (PHP in your case), or if you do want to perform the image load at client-side create an API call that gives you a list of all the images.  Javascript can make 1 call to get that data and then load all the images, safe in the knowledge that they do exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate taking the time. I will try this method see if works well. I will think of a way to add it using php, the reason Im not using it, its because there are way too many images. The main page contains products with one image each, this is added by using php, if user clicks in that product, an overlay layout appears with more images about that product. If I were to add all the images to each products layout in the loading of the page while using php. this would be way too many data.

Comment: No worries - happy to help.  There are ways around having a tonne of images on the page that can still be done with a mix of server & client code.  For example, you can use PHP to create all the image elements but do it in a way that stops them loading in the client.  Then, when they are scrolled into view you load them.  Have a search for lazy loading images, and have a look at https://gamesnap.club for an example.

Comment: OK thanks never heard of lazy loading images before. will google it :)

Comment: Good luck, and have fun :)

Comment: thanks fun is hard sometimes :) but i try my best have a good day!